# Extending ButtonBatButtonStyle to change selection color

Tags: android-layout, android, android-button

I am trying to extend android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle to change the color the selection, currently it is defaulted to the standard ICS blue, and I cant figure out what attribute Id need to change in order to overwrite to achieve the desired result.

I'm trying to crate my own style like so:

```
  <style name="NavButton" parent="android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle">
      <item name="android:background">@color/Green</item> <!-- this is the foreground-->
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, in @drawable create XML button_style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#3399cc"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#999999"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="7dp"
                android:color="#3399cc" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#3399cc"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#3399cc" />

            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and in view:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_urban"
```

Comment: Cant yet, but I will :)